# Filter JSON object with Array of selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How i can filter my JSON object with array.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/armanfeyzi/ss16sn19/)

This is an sample of my json object and code, i want to filter final render HTML by selected checkbox.

Thanks for your help

```
function init(arr){
  var li = '';
  $.each(jsn, function (key, value) {

    if (arr.length == 0) {
      li += '<li>' + jsn[key].name + '</li>';
    }else{
      $(arr).each(function (i, v) {
      // this section must be filter "pack's" but i can't writ correct query
        li += '<li>' + jsn[key].name + '</li>';
      });
    };
    $('#container').html(li);
  })
}
var CheckArr = new Array();
init(CheckArr);

$('#btnFilter').click(function(){
    var CheckArr = new Array();
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      CheckArr.push($(this).attr('value'))
    }
  });
  init(CheckArr);
```

Comment: can you elaborate what do you actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to verify `length` of array outside of `init` function. (for case when function is called for first time).Then, you need to iterate your checkboxes array and search every item in your `json` array(called jsn) to verify condition you need.

Here is solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var jsn = [  
   {  
      "name":"pack01",
      "caplessthan100mb":"False",
      "cap100to500mb":"True",
      "cap500mbto2g":"False",
      "cap2gto10g":"False"
   },
   {  
      "name":"pack02",
      "caplessthan100mb":"True",
      "cap100to500mb":"False",
      "cap500mbto2g":"False",
      "cap2gto10g":"False"
   },
   {  
      "name":"pack03",
      "caplessthan100mb":"False",
      "cap100to500mb":"False",
      "cap500mbto2g":"False",
      "cap2gto10g":"True"
   },
   {  
      "name":"pack04",
      "caplessthan100mb":"False",
      "cap100to500mb":"False",
      "cap500mbto2g":"True",
      "cap2gto10g":"False"
   },
   {  
      "name":"pack05",
      "caplessthan100mb":"False",
      "cap100to500mb":"False",
      "cap500mbto2g":"False",
      "cap2gto10g":"True"
   },
   {  
      "name":"pack06",
      "caplessthan100mb":"True",
      "cap100to500mb":"False",
      "cap500mbto2g":"False",
      "cap2gto10g":"False"
   },
   {  
      "name":"pack07",
      "caplessthan100mb":"False",
      "cap100to500mb":"False",
      "cap500mbto2g":"False",
      "cap2gto10g":"True"
   }
];

function init(arr){
   var li = '';
   if(arr.length==0)
   {
       $.each(jsn, function (key, value) {
          li+= '<li>' + jsn[key].name + '</li>';
       });
   }
   else{
       $(arr).each(function (i, v) {
           $.each(jsn, function (key, value) {
              if(jsn[key][v]=="True")
                 li+= '<li>' + jsn[key].name + '</li>';
           });
       });
   }
   $('#container').html(li);
}
var CheckArr = new Array();
init(CheckArr);

$('#btnFilter').click(function(){
 var CheckArr = new Array();
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      CheckArr.push($(this).attr('value'))
    }
  });
  init(CheckArr);
})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="caplessthan100mb">caplessthan100mb</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="cap100to500mb">cap100to500mb</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="cap500mbto2g">cap500mbto2g</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="cap2gto10g">cap2gto10g</li>
  <li><input type="button" id="btnFilter" value="Filter"></li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul id="container">
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things in your code that could use improvement so I've taken the liberty of largely rewriting it (see jsFiddle link below).

1) First thing is in your data (`jsn`) you are using `"False"` and `"True"` instead of `false` and `true`. That'll make it hard to write your filter condition because `true != "True"`.

2) It's quite hard to debug your code because the variable names aren't very meaningful. I'd highly recommend putting some energy into improving your variable names especially when code isn't working.

For example:

`packsData` instead of `jsn`

`checkedBoxes` instead of `arr`

3) If you try to filter within the .each() below you'll run into trouble when it matches more than one filter condition (it'll be displayed more than once).

```
$(arr).each(function (i, v) {
    // this section must be filter "pack's" but i can't writ correct query
    li += '<li>' + jsn[key].name + '</li>';
});
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v751d2ey/)